# It might not work since ESLint's version is mismatched with the standard config

Tags: javascript, eslint

I ran command `npx eslint --init`. I came across following questions:

```
? Which style guide do you want to follow? … 
  Airbnb: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript
▸ Standard: https://github.com/standard/standard
  Google: https://github.com/google/eslint-config-google
  XO: https://github.com/xojs/eslint-config-xo
```

I selected `Standard`. Then it said:

```
✔ The style guide "standard" requires eslint@^7.12.1. You are currently using eslint@8.10.0.
  Do you want to downgrade? · No / Yes
```

I selected `No`.

Then I said:

```
Note: it might not work since ESLint's version is mismatched with the standard config.
```

Should I be ideally downgrading? Or should I not be using standard style guide altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the repo, `eslint-config-standard@17.x.y` [by default works with eslint 8.8.0](https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/master/package.json#L18) (even though it's still a pre-release).

I assume you are still receiving 16.x version, which [defaults to `eslint@7.18.0`](https://github.com/standard/standard/blob/16.x/package.json#L17).

Which exact version of  `eslint-config-standard` does running `npx eslint --init` give you?

If you are using this for a new project, I recommend you go with `eslint-config-standard@next`. The project is very actively maintained, and their main focus currently is to lift everything to ESLint 8.x, so it will not be a long wait.

Comment: Seems you are correct. Running `npm list` gives `eslint-config-standard@16.0.3` in the installed package list.  **Q1.**  Why this is so? Is it because all [`17.x`](https://github.com/standard/standard/releases/tag/v17.0.0-0) onwards are all `pre-release`? **Q2.**  Also why it didnt pick the latest non-pre-release [`16.0.4`](https://github.com/standard/standard/releases/tag/v16.0.4) instead of [16.0.3](https://github.com/standard/standard/releases/tag/v16.0.3)?

Comment: `eslint-config-standard@latest` resolves to version 16.0.3 ([latest tag in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-standard/v/latest)).

Comment: Aah, so what could be the solution / preferred approach? Should I downgrade eslint, or should I go for pre-release versions? Also how do I force `npm` install latest pre-release?

Comment: The problem is that `@eslint/create-config` is hard-coded to use the `latest` version: https://github.com/eslint/create-config/blob/9cee9035e9c32d58be23611859490e7e22e51c65/lib/init/config-initializer.js#L263 - You'd need to patch that to use `next` instead.

Comment: By "patch", do you mean to simply replace `latest` to `next` on the [line 263](https://github.com/eslint/create-config/blob/9cee9035e9c32d58be23611859490e7e22e51c65/lib/init/config-initializer.js#L263) of my local file: `<project_path>/node_modules/@eslint/create-config/lib/init/config-initializer.js`?

Comment: I would rather install the required dependencies myself.

Comment: So all I have to do it is `yarn remove eslint-config-standard` and then `yarn add eslint-config-standard@next`? Will eslint pick it up correctly? Or I have to do some more configuration / tweaking? Well, I just tried out that and it installed version `17.0.0-1`. Why? Is it what is associated with `next` tag? But, I [don't find](https://github.com/standard/standard/releases/tag/v17.0.0-1) the tag associated with this version.

Comment: You can find it under releases on the main branch.